Is there a way to extract the search from a c++ regex? (not a question about regexs but #include <regex>)
given a C++ std regex is there a way to figure out what that regex would search for?  get the string out that you put in when constructing it?
I've seen https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex and that doesn't list anything helpfull here.  The only thing I can thing of is generating every possible string and seeing what matches but that seems like an insane solution to this.  sizeof(regex) is a constant 32 no matter how long I make the search text so some abusive memory manipulation is out of the question.  I've tried casting to strings and char *s thinking maybe most of the other details about it would be known at compile time and look to be handled in the type.  This feels like something that should be doable.  Large codebase that I do not own so doing something like wrapping the regex in a class that can be implicitly converted to a regex but that also separately stores the search as a string is out of the question.

Probably impossible. std::basic_regex typically doesn't store the pattern, it parses it to an engine that be queried with other string. Regex pattern is discarded as soon as constructor/assignment ends.

"This feels like something that should be doable." -- Why? (If you were implementing a regular expression parser, would you prefer to parse the pattern once at construction or to parse it every time the regular expression is used?)

Does this answer your question? How do you check if two regex's describe the same pattern?

No.*
There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of what a regular expression is here. A regex is a directed graph that represents a pattern. When you apply it to a string, what you are doing is nothing more testing whether or not the string matches the pattern by successfully traversing the graph.
Humans like convenience. It would be really painful to have to construct the graph by hand, or to have to use a specialized graph-drawing program to generate the code that constructs it.
So instead we use a very convenient text string that represents the graph, which we tend to refer to as a “regular expression”, even though it is just a textual representation of a regular expression graph. Regex construction takes that string and builds the actual DFA (or NFA) graph. Thereafter we use that graph to match against any strings we wish.
* So, yes, we could get the textual regex string out of the graph if we were to write the code to decompose the constructed graph back into a character string, but no one ever needs to do that! Why would we?
** The question, as asked, is unclear. It appears to me that the OP is asking how to get the string used to construct the regex back out of a compiled regex.

What I really wanted was to extract some unique representation of the regex so I could test if 2 regex's where identical and I would like it to be a textual representation so I could test that across multiple executions of the program and human readable enough that I could identify a regex as coming from an initial string.  If there is a standard way to extract the information held in this graph from a regex type that would be great if not w/e

Ah. How do you check if two regex's describe the same pattern? may be of use to you. But the Standard Library, AFAIK, does not offer that functionality.

No not really.  That is about 2 regexs not the C++ std implementation, is asking if the 2 are equivalent (where I only care if the two are identical or even close really), and it's answer is "it is not provable impossible to implement in flex"

Er, that answer says it is decidable, and gives yet another link (sorry) to a post that recommends you compute a minimal DFA, which would indeed tell you whether two regexes compile to the same pattern. Again, the Standard Library does not offer that functionality. So... unless you do it yourself (or find a library that does it for you), then answer is “not using Standard C++”.

I mean even extracting the automata from the regex object would be the step I need to do what i need but it looks like there isnt a way to do that so oh well.

@Smasheded Yes, basically. Unless you know intimate details of the std::regex (which you don’t, at least not in any cross-platform or necessarily even cross-version way) or parse it into a minimal DFA yourself, then there is no reasonable way.

As the question does not provide the precise motivation and aim, I suppose it is still worth mentioning, that on practical level, the regex classes tend to have a private member  _Visualization which is precisely  "the string out that you put in when constructing it".
Which is obviously non-canonical, but may be what @Smasheded is after.
